# Is it possible to embed a list of my +1s to my website?

Tags: google-plus-1

I use +1s extensively to bookmark/suggest webpages. I have already set them to be publicly visible on my google+ profile, but I'd like to also show them on my website. Is there some embed code I can use so this list of +1s shows up on my website?

In the interest of making the question as general as possible, I asked about any website. However, my intention is to do this on my wordpress blog.

PS: I know you can use google checkout to export all the +1s and then re-format them so they can be imported to wordpress. However, that solution would require for me to manually update the listing every so often and I'd like to avoid the hassle.